# Java SOAPMessage insert Element

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have SOAPMessage, which created from parsed xml-file. How can I insert a new Element (SOAPElement or Node) between two other elements? Now it appends only like last child (with addChildElement or appendChild), in the end of current NodeList. The method insertBefore throws the exception:

"org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. "

Comment: Are you trying duplicate root element? Are you trying add node below or above root element?

Comment: Hm, no, i'm not. I just started to learn soap in java, please, could you show the example - what do you mean?

Comment: Are you researched info in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778140/why-i-get-org-w3c-dom-domexception-hierarchy-request-err-here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520982/org-w3c-dom-domexception-hierarchy-request-err
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864285/hierarchy-request-err-while-trying-to-add-elements-to-xml-file-in-a-for-loop

Comment: I'll start right now, thank you